# Can I run any c or c++ spesific commands at linux terminal without excecute?

Tags: c++, c

I want to test as fast as *C/C++* functions how works.

Assume I don't know how `printf` works. Kind newbie 
I glanced man pages and learned this prints out what I want, but I need to try how it's work immediately.

Or
I need a try a `math.h` function like `pow(2,3)` I need to ensure which term powered 2<sup>3</sup> or 3<sup>2</sup>

so on...

Can I get output of specific command without compile, debug, execute?

like

```
echo "sqrt(4)" | bc
2
```

This is work, but I need to try more command `pow`, `acos` etc moreover tons of library function!

Is there any way to do on Linux terminal?

Comment: You can use a C++ script language like [ChaiScript](http://chaiscript.com/)

Comment: Maybe just use Python...

Comment: _"I want to test as fast as C/C++ functions how works."_: I'm not quite sure what is is supposed to mean, but why not just learn the language?

Comment: You might want to look at tinycc https://bellard.org/tcc/

Comment: There *are* C interpreters which let you do exactly what you want.  But these days, compiling is so fast that the compile/execute loop isn't much of a hindrance, especially within a good IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I get output of specific command without compile, debug, execute?

No. You have to compile and then execute a C or a C++ program.

> Is there any way to do on Linux terminal?

You can write a small script that creates a temporary file, compiles the code, runs it and then removes the temporary file. Save the following file in `PATH`, ex. as `/usr/local/bin/ccrun` or as `~/bin/ccrun` and add `~/bin` to `PATH`. Remember to add executable permissions.

```
#!/bin/sh
tmp=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm "$tmp"' EXIT
gcc -xc - -o "$tmp" && ./"$tmp" "$@"
```

then you can:

```
printf "%s\n" "#include <stdio.h>" "int main() { printf("%d\n", 5); }" | ccrun
```

or inline, without script:

```
printf "%s\n" "#include <stdio.h>" 'int main() { printf("%d\n", 5); }' | ( gcc -xc - && ./a.out; rm ./a.out )
```

But it's simpler to try functions in one of online compilers, there are so many of them, and you do not need to install and change anything - just your browser is enough. https://godbolt.org/ http://cpp.sh/ https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler to name a few of my first google hits for "online C++ compiler". The popular site with C and C++ documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf has examples with "run this code", then you can edit the code and execute it.

PS. I may share scripts [,ccrun](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamilscripts/-/blob/master/bin/%2Cccrun) and [,c++run](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamilscripts/-/blob/master/bin/%2Cc%2B%2Brun) that work just like the script above with some special semantics that like add all possible `#include`s (but c++ is super slow then) to the source file and add `-fsanitize` options to the file when compiling and running. The scripts are mostly unfinished and were made for very simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I run any c or c++ spesific commands at linux terminal

No. There are several alternative shell programs. None of the shell languages are the C++ language and they cannot "run C++ commands".

> I need to ensure which term powered 2<sup>3</sup> or 3<sup>2</sup>

For integer powers, the `bc` calculator has you covered:

```
echo "2 ^ 3" | bc
```